# Google analytics event in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics

I want to make my events clear (eg. Video) rather than the GA plugin in WP makes them (eg. download, outbound, mailto)

But i don't see my custom events in my GA. I have tried the following two and more. What am i doing wrong, why can't i see my events?

```
</a class="button button_normal button_#85bc20" target="_blank" href="linkto page" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'download', 'ux-kickoff');"> Download Slides </a>
```

```
<a href="link" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'download', 'ux-kickoff');">

[button link="link" download target="_blank" title="Download Session" size="normal" color="#85bc20"]</a>
```

Comment: Syntax looks okay. Open the developer tool in your browser and look at the console if this throws any javascript errors. Check that the analytics.js file is loaded, that the tracker object is created, that the default tracker name is used (else you'll get a message like "unknown target") and that the ga function has not been renamed (type "ga" in the console, if it print "undefined" the ga function is not there or has been renamed).

Comment: thanks ill give it a try, im still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your anchor tag isn't set up correctly, should be `<a></a>` whereas yours is `</a></a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
function send_event_to_google_analytics() {
// Set the parameters for the Measurement Protocol API call
$googleAnalyticsUrl = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect';
$analyticsId = 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X'; // Replace with your Analytics ID
$clientId = '12345'; // Replace with a unique ID for the user or session
$eventCategory = 'Example';
$eventAction = 'Click';
$eventLabel = 'Button';

// Build the Measurement Protocol API call
$payload = [
    'v' => '1',
    'tid' => $analyticsId,
    'cid' => $clientId,
    't' => 'event',
    'ec' => $eventCategory,
    'ea' => $eventAction,
    'el' => $eventLabel
];

// Send the Measurement Protocol API call
$response = wp_remote_post($googleAnalyticsUrl, [
    'body' => $payload,
]);

if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    error_log('Failed to send event to Google Analytics: ' . $response->get_error_message());
    return;
}

// Handle the response from the server (if necessary)
```

}

// Call the function to send the event to Google Analytics
send_event_to_google_analytics();